# Is there any way to detect if an ad is broken?

Tags: wordpress, web, adsense, ads

So I have this website where I use all kind of ads : banners, etc. Some of them are broken, it shows nothing when I insert the code. Is the any way to solve this automaticaly? Like to spot which codes are not working and use another code instead?

Thanks.